# Android, detect socket write failure

Tags: java, android, sockets, ioexception

Basically the server side sends a keep alive message every 8 minutes, if the write fails it disconnects the client and closes the socket connection. If my android device is awake and the server closes the connection then the read operation on the android device throws an exception as it should and i disconnect from the server. If the device is asleep it doesn't read data at all even with a partial wake lock and a wifilock, i have already given up on that, but my actual problem is when my device comes back from sleep (if i turn the screen on for example) what i do is send a message to the server so i can refresh the data but if my server has already closed the socket my write operation should throw an IOException but for some reason it doesn't. And even the blocking read i have doesn't throw any exception or return -1.

here is my write operation:

```
public boolean sendData(byte[] data)
{
    boolean sent=false;
    if(connectedToServer)
    {
        try 
        {
            myOutputStream.write(data, 0, data.length);
            sent= true;
        }
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            unexpectedDisconnectionFromServer();
        }
    }
    return sent;
}
```

and here is my read operation:

```
public void startReadingInBackground()
{
    while(connectedToServer)
    {
        try
        {
            int bytesRead=0;
            if(myWifiLock!=null && !myWifiLock.isHeld())
                myWifiLock.acquire();
            byte val=(byte)myInputStream.read();
            myWakeLock.acquire();
            if(val==-1)
            {
                unexpectedDisconnectionFromServer();
                if(myWifiLock!=null && myWifiLock.isHeld())
                    myWifiLock.release();
                myWakeLock.release();
                return;
            }
            bytesRead=myInputStream.read(myBuffer, 0, bufferSize);
            if(bytesRead<1)
            {
                unexpectedDisconnectionFromServer();
                if(myWifiLock!=null && myWifiLock.isHeld())
                    myWifiLock.release();
                myWakeLock.release();
                return;
            }
            byte[] dataArray=Arrays.copyOfRange(myBuffer,0,bytesRead);
            ByteBuffer data=ByteBuffer.allocate(bytesRead+1).put(val).put(dataArray);
            myParent.invokeReceiveAction(data, bytesRead + 1);
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            if(!myWakeLock.isHeld())
                myWakeLock.acquire();
            unexpectedDisconnectionFromServer();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            if(myWifiLock!=null && myWifiLock.isHeld())
                myWifiLock.release();
            if(myWakeLock!=null && myWakeLock.isHeld())
                myWakeLock.release();
        }
    }
}
```

and i get the outputstream like so:

```
Socket mySocket = new Socket(SERVER_IP, SERVER_PORT_TCP );
myOutputStream=mySocket.getOutputStream();
```

Comment: is there a reason why you are not using `DataInputStream` and manually reading from the socket?

Comment: @Adeeb i am using an `InputStream`

Comment: 1. I don't understand why you need to acquire a wifi lock for a heartbeat/keep-alive function. surely a mobile network would be sufficient even wifi is turned off. 2. you can use an InputStream if you wish, however, a DataInputStream results in cleaner code as i am under the impression that all reads to it block until there is data available so you don't need while loops.

Comment: @Adeeb an `InputStream` block as well. In both cases i will still need a while loop to keep reading from the server. The wifi lock was just a last resort because as i explained i was trying to receive keep alive messages while the device was asleep

Answer (score 0):

Your write *will* throw an `IOException,` *eventually.* Your mistake is in assuming it is bound to happen on the first write after the disconnect. It won't, for all sorts of reasons including buffering and retries. TCP has to determine that the connection is really dead before it will reject a new write, and it certainly won't do that on the first write after the disconnect.

Comment: well if the device is awake the read operation return with -1 right away, but when asleep the read doesn't return at all even when the server sends data. is there a way to make sure the device receives data when it is asleep. Like how does viber wake up the device when someone calls?